# Looping Dictionary with unexpected returns

Tags: python, python-3.x

It has been a long night and day. I could use some help why this is not working can not think straight. This script opens a .csv file checks if a certain word is contained in a the title which is at row[4] and then it will loop through a dictionary that contains list and if the word is in the title then it will return the dictionary key to be written to a new csv file.

What I am getting is uncategorized for every row which should not be correct because the title does contain words in the list.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Example CSV in BrandsMart USA,http://www.BrandsMartUSA.com,BrandsMart Product Catalog,01:30.8,Mini Bass King Jr Bluetooth Portable Outdoor Speaker,2Boom BX320K,2Boom BX320K Mini Bass King Jr Bluetooth Portable Outdoor Speaker,2BOOMBX320K,2Boom,BX320K,7.08192E+11,,USD,,19.88,19.88,,http://www.example.com,http://www.ftjcfx.com/image-8299186-11133500,https://www.brandsmartusa.com/images/product/large/20225377.jpg,Bluetooth & Docking Speakers,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,yes,,,
BrandsMart USA,http://www.BrandsMartUSA.com,BrandsMart Product Catalog,01:30.8,Mini Bass King Jr Bluetooth Portable Outdoor Speaker,2Boom BX320R,2Boom BX320R Mini Bass King Jr Bluetooth Portable Outdoor Speaker,2BOOMBX320R,2Boom,BX320R,7.08192E+11,,USD,,19.88,19.88,,http://www.example.com,http://www.ftjcfx.com/image-8299186-11133500,https://www.brandsmartusa.com/images/product/large/20225393.jpg,Bluetooth & Docking Speakers,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,yes,,,
BrandsMart USA,http://www.BrandsMartUSA.com,BrandsMart Product Catalog,01:30.8,Bluetooth Noise-Cancelling Earbud Headphones,2Boom EPBT690B,2Boom EPBT690B Bluetooth Noise-Cancelling Earbud Headphones,2BOOMEPBT690B,2Boom,EPBT690B,7.44751E+11,,USD,,9.88,9.88,,http://www.example.com,http://www.ftjcfx.com/image-8299186-11133500,https://www.brandsmartusa.com/images/product/large/20225398.jpg,Earbuds,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,yes,,,

Using Python 3

```
import os, csv, time

csv_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

row_list = []

# Appliances
category_list = {"Appliance Accessories": ['Air Conditioner Accessories', 'Air Purifier Accessories', "Coffee Maker Accessories",
                           'Dishwasher Accessories', 'Food Processor Accessories', 'Heater Accessories',
                           'Humidifier Accessories', 'Humidifier Accessories', 'Mixer Accessories',
                           'Range & Oven Accessories', 'Range Hood Accessories', 'Refrigerator Accessories',
                           'Vacuum Accessories', 'Washer & Dryer Accessories'],
 "Electronics Accessories": ['cables & adapters', 'audio accessories', 'video accessories', 'camcorder accessories',
                             'cell phone accessories', 'clock radios', 'Digital Book Reader Accessories',
                             'Digital Picture Frames', 'Electronics Cases & Bags', 'GPS Accessories',
                             'Projector Accessories', 'Telephone Accessories', 'batteries', 'battery'],
 "Photography": ['Camcorders', 'Cameras', 'Digital Camera Accessories', 'Digital Cameras', 'Camera', 'Digital Camera',
                 'Photography', 'Darkroom']}

category = ""

with open(csv_path + "/pre.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        for k, val in category_list.items():
            for v in val:
                if v.lower() in row[4].lower():
                    category = k
                else:
                    category = "Uncategorized"


        new_row = [str(row[0]),  # company
                   str(row[1]),  # company url
                   str(row[4]),  # product name
                   str(row[5]),  # keywords
                   str(row[6]),  # descripition
                   str(row[7]),  # sku
                   str(row[8]),  # manufacturer
                   str(row[13]),  # saleprice
                   str(row[14]),  # price
                   str(row[15]),  # retailprice
                   str(row[17]),  # buy_link
                   str(row[19]),  # product_image_url
                   str(row[31]),  # promotional_text
                   str(row[36]),  # stock
                   str(row[37]),  # condition
                   str(row[38]),  # warrenty
                   str(row[39]),  # shipping_cost
                   category,
                   ]
        row_list.append(new_row)

    f.close()

with open(csv_path + "/final.csv", 'w') as ff:
    writer = csv.writer(ff)
    writer.writerows(row_list)
    ff.close()
```

Comment: Could you give an example row from the csv you expect to be categorized?

Comment: added example thanks

Comment: As an aside, no need to `str(row[0])` , its already a string. Or `f.close()`, the `with` clause does that automatically.

Comment: I had to write str(row[0]) because I was getting an error on columns which stated "int base 10" the only way I could get it to run

Answer (score 3):

Well, this block will only store the result of the last value in `val`:

```
for v in val:
    if v.lower() in row[4].lower():
        category = k
    else:
        category = "Uncategorized"
```

It's only comparing `val[-1]` in the end, since you're overwriting `category`.

You probably want to break the loop once you find a category, or do something with this value on each iteration?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I took a little bit from everyone above to achieve my needs. Thank you all that helped.

```
csv_row_map =  [0,  # company
                1,  # company url
                4,  # product name
                5,  # keywords
                6,  # descripition
                7,  # sku
                8,  # manufacturer
                13,  # saleprice
                14,  # price
                15,  # retailprice
                17,  # buy_link
                19,  # product_image_url
                31,  # promotional_text
                36,  # stock
                37,  # condition
                38,  # warrenty
                39,  # shipping_cost
                ]

product_to_category_index = {}
for category, products in category_list.items():
    product_to_category_index.update(((product.lower(), category) for product in products))

with open(csv_path + '/pre.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        for k, v in product_to_category_index.items():
            if k in row[4].lower():
                category = v
                break
            else:
                category = "Uncategorized"
        #category = product_to_category_index.get(row[4].lower(), "Uncategorized")
        new_row = [row[csv_row_map[i]] for i in range(len(csv_row_map))]
        new_row.append(category)
        row_list.append(new_row)

with open(csv_path + "/final.csv", 'w') as ff:
    writer = csv.writer(ff)
    writer.writerows(row_list)
```